# Can I be in a relationship with my Godfather’s daughter?

Tags: marriage

I’m a male that is part of a Catholic family and I’m wondering if I can be in a relationship with my Godfather’s daughter. Me and my Godfather or anyone of his side of his side of his family are not blood-related to me nor my father or mother’s side. I am unsure if we can be together or marry. (I’m an idiot so I have little to no knowledge about most things)

Comment: Welcome to C.SE.  To clarify your question, are you seeking a Catholic answer, which makes sense if you, your Godfather, and his daughter are all practicing Catholics?  Answers in C.SE need to be objective, so if there are different answers from denominations that practice Godfather & Godmother sponsorship, the question will need to be tagged accordingly.